# Is it possible to Generate a Field given both the addition and multiplication table.

Tags: finite-fields, gap

So, I've been told to research a little about GAP functions related with fields, this far I can get the "standard" representation of any field with GF(p) or GF(p^r) and a representation of GF(p^r) given the polynomial used to extend GF(p), pol by using AlgrebraicExtension(GF(p), pol). Now I was wondering is there is any way of generating a field if you were given both tables.

I've tried some things using Magma's and Ring's commands but I haven't been able to get anything this far.

Thanking you in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While the general system setup would not preclude you from implementing such functionality (you'd likely end up with needing 500-1000 lines of code to implement everything needed), there isn't any existing function that would create a field from a multiplication table.

A sneaky (in letter but not in spirit) way of answering (I presume your tables are finite) would be to take
`GF(Length(multiplicationtable))` if the table is of size $\le 2^{16}$. (but that would not give you a correspondence between table indices and field elements).

Comment: Ok thank you very much :D